# Get data of a chart from another web page and save it into a variable. The data appears while hovering the graphic. Using php if possible

Tags: php, canvas, charts, hover, graphic

I have been looking for the solution of this problem for more that 2 weeks but I cant find it out by myself...

I basically want to get the data that appears while hovering on a chart **[like this](https://jsfiddle.net/2w8hany2)**.

The fiddle is just an example of the kind of graphic that i want to get the data from. When you hover the chart of the fiddle, a tooltip appears. I want to create an script to get the data from that tooltip

An example of a web page with this kind of charts would be **[this one](http://champion.gg/champion/Heimerdinger)**

I want to save the data in a sql database. (This is not a problem)

The closest thing i have to this is this script to get data from a div... Maybe it helps

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$doc->recover = true;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTMLFile('url');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$query = "//div[@class='class-name']";
$entries = $xpath->query($query);
$tem = $entries->item(0)->textContent;
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: To get the `data` you could use a web crawler: https://subinsb.com/how-to-create-a-simple-web-crawler-in-php

Comment: If you want just the data, why not make a curl request and then scrape the JSON data out of the code. Google's chart drawing tool makes these tips from that data.

Comment: any idea about where can i find a cURL tuturial?